# js code to start with "$( window ).load(function()"

Tags: javascript, pageload

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(".faded1").each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(i * 100).fadeIn();
});

</script>
```

and i want this function to be activated after page load..

with: $( window ).load(function()

how can i do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Seriously? You can pass a function as an argument to `each()` function, but not to [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function run(){
    $(".faded1").each(function(i) {
      $(this).delay(i * 100).fadeIn();
    });

    }
$( window ).load(function(){
run();
});
```

call the above function after page load r include in  $( window ).load(function()});

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you simply do
`$(document).ready(function(){
$(".faded1").each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(i * 100).fadeIn();
});
});`

Comment: Maybe because OP wants to execute the code after `window.onload` has been triggered...